# Synonym for confront, without an extremely negative connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, connotation

I'm looking for a word like confront- where it has a slightly negative connotation; like it's something that is uncomfortable, but not extremely bad.
Examples:

> I had to __________ people who weren't doing their work.

> The CEO had to _______ some of the problems in the work place.

The Thesaurus synonyms are:

- defy -- no, the meaning I require is more like speaking sternly to someone rather than defying them
- encounter -- this is too neutral
- meet -- neutral
- oppose -- again, it's like a conversation, not an opposition.

Comment: It seems you don't want "extremely negative", and you don't want "slightly negative", and you don't like "neutral"...so what are you actually looking for?

Comment: I am looking for slightly negative :)

Comment: So what is wrong with "confront"? This is starting to sound like Goldilocks...

Comment: directly address / formally address

Comment: 'Correct' is possibly as unemotive as it gets here. 'Realign' is getting silly.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with confront-- I just used it too many times.

Answer (score 0):

*handle* could work; it's fairly informal, but has a slight aura of 'doing what has to be done clinically':

> [to] manage (a situation or problem)
>
> ([Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=to%20handle%20define))

Or *approach*:

> to deal with something
> to speak to, write to, or visit someone in order to do something such as make a request or business agreement
>
> ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/approach))
>
> to make advances to, especially in order to create a desired result
>
> ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/approach))

Answer (score 0):

**Goad** seems to work well for this sentence:

> I had to *goad* people who weren't doing their work.

*AHD* gives:

> To prod or urge with or as if with a long pointed stick.

Answer (score 0):

The definition with the most obvious 'not too harshly' caveat that I've come across is:

> **reprove** implies an often kindly intent to correct a fault.
>
> - *gently reproved my table manners*

But the following have reasonably appropriate caveats:

> **admonish** suggests earnest or friendly warning and counsel.
>
> - admonished by my parents to control expenses
>
> **reproach** and **chide** suggest displeasure or disappointment expressed in mild reproof or scolding.
>
> - *reproached him for tardiness*
> - *chided by their mother for untidiness*

[[Merriam-Webster: choose the right synonym for *chide*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chide)]

The above obviously apply to the confrontation context; 'deal with' etc for problems rather than personalities are pretty neutral as it is. As @tblue says, 'address' is fine.

Answer (score -1):

Chastise, scold, or reprimand would work in the first blank of the situation you provided.

For the CEO, try "address." It's not exactly negative, but depending on the context of the issues, it could work.

Comment: "Chastise, scold, or reprimand " all sound very negative, and the OP is looking for _one_ word to describe both situations.